# Cloud Endpoints Auth returning JWT Issuer is not configured when using Access Token from CICP/Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase-authentication, jwt, access-token, google-cloud-endpoints

Right now my OpenAPI yaml looks like this:

[image]

And my Access Token coming out of my JWT in raw format looks like this:

[image]

The Google-Issuer and the JWT iss are the exact same, the JWT kid matches the key ids inside the link provided by the google-jwks_uri, and the google-audiences match the aud.So, really, I can't see why this wouldn't work, and yet when i call the api with the Bearer access token i receive a 401 and "Jwt issuer is not configured".

Comment: The [`x-google-adueinces`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions?hl=es-419#x-google-audiences) is still in Beta, and it can change. Could you please share the full response/error you are facing? According to the docs [`x-google-issuer`](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-extensions#x-google-issuer) should take the form of a hostname or email address. The value seems to be pretty short. Could you please double check is the correct value?

Comment: @BraulioBaron The value is correct according to this: https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase

Answer (score 0):

@BryceSoker I ran into a similar problem and found that changing

x-google-issuer: "https://accounts.google.com"
to
x-google-issuer: "accounts.google.com"

to match the "iss": "accounts.google.com" in the ID token fixed the problem.