# Cloud Endpoints returning 401 Jwt issuer is not configured

Tags: python, jwt, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-run

I am trying to set up service to service authentication so an external application can make requests to a Cloud Run application (behind a Cloud Endpoints API gateway).

I have followed the Cloud Endpoints [authentication between services](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication) documentation, however I continue to receive the following error when trying to reach the Cloud Run service:

> 401: Jwt issuer is not configured

Within the openapi spec, I have setup endpoint security and securityDefinition:

```
/endpoint_1:
  get:
     ...
     security:
       - service_account: []

securityDefinitions:
  service_account:
    authorizationUrl: ""
    flow: "implicit"
    type: "oauth2"
    x-google-issuer: "<service_account_email>"
    x-google-jwks_uri: "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<service_account_email>"
    x-google-audiences: "https://<cloud-run-service>-pjcfvhz2qq-uc.a.run.app"
```

This was then deployed to Cloud Run using ESPv2 Beta as described the [Cloud Endpoints documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-cloud-run).

After everything is deployed, I am trying to run the following script from my local machine to generate a signed jwt and make a request to the Cloud Run service:

```
import os
import json
import time
import requests
import google.auth.crypt
import google.auth.jwt

now = int(time.time())
expiry_length = 3600
sa_email = '<service_account_email>'

payload = {
    'iat': now,
    'exp': now + expiry_length,
    'iss': sa_email,
    'sub': sa_email,
    'email': sa_email,
    'aud': 'https://<cloud-run-service>-pjcfvhz2qq-uc.a.run.app',
}

file_path = "service-account.json"

signer = google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_file(file_path)
signed_jwt = google.auth.jwt.encode(signer, payload)

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(signed_jwt.decode('utf-8')),
    'content-type': 'application/json',
}

url = "https://<cloud-run-service>-pjcfvhz2qq-uc.a.run.app/endpoint_1"
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res.json())
```

response of the get request:

> {'message': 'Jwt issuer is not configured', 'code': 401}

The issuer has been specified on the openapi spec as the service account email which matches the issuer used with generating the JWT.

Any guidance on what **Jwt issuer is not configured** actually means, is appreciated.

Comment: duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61507102/cloud-endpoints-auth-returning-jwt-issuer-is-not-configured-when-using-access-to

Comment: @Chaos I have tried accounts.google.com as the issuer, after seeing that post, but without success. I also am not sure it's relevant to service accounts, but rather id tokens like what is provided from firebase auth.

Comment: I see you are basing the `securityDefinitions:` fields of the OpenAPI spec based on [this information](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase). Nonetheless, since you are using the ESPv2 Beta I think you should update those specs according to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/migrate-to-esp-v2#handle-jwt).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need a Google signed JWT token and not a self signed token. Try to change the end of your code with this (after your `signed_jwt = ...` line)

```
    auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

    params = {
        'assertion': signed_jwt, # You may need to decode the signed_jwt: signed_jwt.decode('utf-8')
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    }

    r = requests.post(auth_url, data=params)

    if r.ok:
        id_token = r.json()['id_token']

        headers = {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(id_token),
            'content-type': 'application/json',
        }

        url = "https://<cloud-run-service>-pjcfvhz2qq-uc.a.run.app/endpoint_1"
        res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        print(res.json())

    # For debugging
    print(r)
    print(vars(r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you deploy ESPv2 Cloud-Run service with the flag "--allow-unauthenticated"?   If no, the ESPv2 cloud-run service is protected by IAM server,  it will verify the JWT token and pass in a new token to ESPv2.  ESPv2 will not recognize its issuer from the new token.

In order for ESPv2 JWT authentication to work, you have to disable IAM for ESPv2 cloud-run by passing the flag  "--allow-unauthenticated" in "gcloud run deploy" command.